# Monitor specific app network speed and ping Android

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, social-media, qos

I need to develop an application for android platform that can measure delay, upload and download speed for a specific app. The goal is to monitor quality of service of some social media network. The app should be written in Kotlin.

I would really appreciate it if someone could give me a hint and/or help me find a library that could be useful.